# Confused by Lemma 2.15 of Mendelson

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am confused by the proof of Lemma 2.15 in Mendelson. The proof is a bit long, but here's what's happening in the confusing part for me:

1. Given a theory $K$, let $(S_0),...,(S_{n-1})$ be wffs in a proof that ends with a wff $F_n(b)$, so that $\vdash_K F_n(b)$, where $b$ is a new constant that does not occur in $(S_0),...,(S_{n-1})$. Each $S_k$ for $k=0$ to $k=n$ has the following form:

$$
(S_k):=(\exists x_k) \neg F_k(x_k) \rightarrow \neg F_k(b_k)
$$

2. From $\vdash_K F_n(b)$, we have $\vdash_K F_n(x)$, where $x$ is a new variable, i.e. $F_n(x)$ is derived from $F_n(b)$ by replacing all occurences of $b$ in the proof with $x$.
3. From $\vdash_K F_n(x)$, we have $\vdash_K (\forall x) F_n(x)$ using universal generalization.

The rest of the proof then continues from here ...

I am unsure about step 3 above. Shouldn't this be $(\forall x)(\exists x)F_n(x)$ ?, i.e. it looks like that we applied universal generalization to $x$, where $x$ is a substitute for a constant $b$

... What am I missing here ?

Comment: "where the constant $b$ came from an existential instantiation" The proof (page 86) does not state that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes, that's correct. I will edit

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, in Lemma 2.15, $b$ is a "scapegoat", i.e. a constant such that $\neg F(b)$ is true. Substituting $b$ with the variable $x$, we get $\neg F(x)$. This makes sense since $x$ is a new variable in the proof. However, if $b$ is a special "scapegoat variable", and $x$ is a substitute for $b$, why is the generalization $\forall x F(x)$ valid ? This implies that all possible interpretations of $b$ would be true, which is not valid since $b$ is a special scapegoat ...

Comment: The intuition here is that $F_n(b)$ was proved without using any information  about $b$. (I hope Mendelson said that the $S_i$, which don't contain $b$, are all of the hypotheses used in the proof.) So, even though $b$ is a constant symbol, its value could be anything, so the proof actually shows that $F_n$ holds of all elements, i.e. $\forall x\,F_n(x)$. The maneuver of replacing $b$ by a variable and then  using universal generalization is a way of fitting this intuition into the formal system.

Comment: It is simply [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization): the formal version seems a little bit tricky but it is the formal counterpart of the intuition "what holds of any holds of all". This means that if in a certain "context" (identified by the set $\Gamma$ of assumptions) we prove some statement $\varphi$ about an "unspecified object" - where the formal counterpart of "unspecified" is expressed via a totally new variable **or** constant - that statement will hold for **every** object (in that context), i.e. we have proved $\forall x \varphi$.